# Route [student.update] not defined. using laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

i am a beginner of laravel. i ran into the problem with Route [student.update] not defined. using laravel 7. when run the laravel project. what i tried so far i attached below.
i attached the controller and view and route file  below i don't what was a problem.

**Controller**

```
public function edit(Student $student)
{ 
    return view('edit')->with('student',$student);
}


public function update(Request $request, Student $student)
{
    Student::update([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'phone' => $request->phone,
        'address' => $request->address,
        'created_at' => now(),
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('student.index')->with('success', 'Student has been Updatedddd');
}
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('student.update',$student->id) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
  
     <div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Name:</strong>
                <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $student->name  }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Phone:</strong>
                <input class="form-control"  name="phone" value="{{ $student->phone  }}"  placeholder="Phone"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Address:</strong>
                <input class="form-control"  name="address" value="{{ $student->address  }}"  placeholder="Address"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
   
</form>
```

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout')
 
@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Laravel 7 CRUD Example from scratch - ItSolutionStuff.com</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
            <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('student.create')}}"> Create New Student</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   
    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
        </div>
    @endif
  
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th width="280px">Action</th>

        </tr>
  
        @foreach ($students as $student)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $student->id  }}</td>
            <td>{{ $student->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $student->phone }}</td>
            <td>{{ $student->address }}</td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('student.edit',$student->id) }}">Edit</a>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
    {!! $students->links() !!}      
@endsection
```

Routes

```
Route::get('/students/{student}', 'StudentController@edit')->name('student.edit');
Route::get('/students/{student}', 'StudentController@update')->name('student.update');
```

Comment: Your route must be post insted of get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update route is defined as a get route while your edit form is trying to submit a post request to the route

You should ideally have the update route defined as a PUT or PATCH route. And if you are using Laravel 8.x, then you should have FQCN for the controllers

```php
//import use statements at the top
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
//use App\Http\Controllers\StudentController; 

Route::match(['PUT', 'PATCH'], '/students/{student}', [StudentController::class, 'update'])->name('student.update');
```

And then make a PUT or PATCH submit request from edit.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('student.update',$student->id) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT') //Method spoofing
  
     <div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Name:</strong>
                <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $student->name  }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Phone:</strong>
                <input class="form-control"  name="phone" value="{{ $student->phone  }}"  placeholder="Phone"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Address:</strong>
                <input class="form-control"  name="address" value="{{ $student->address  }}"  placeholder="Address"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
   
</form>
```

And change the controller method

```php
public function update(Request $request, Student $student)
{
    $student->update([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'phone' => $request->phone,
        'address' => $request->address,
        'created_at' => now(),
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('student.index')->with('success', 'Student has been Updatedddd');
}
```

Comment: sir have one doubt Route::match(['PUT', 'PATCH']  how is it work.           Route::post can't we put

Comment: sir working please tell me the differt of   Route::match(['PUT', 'PATCH'] and  Route::post

Comment: First argument to Route::match() is an array which will instruct Laravel to match any of the methods within the array - so in this case it will match either PUT or PATCH request. As per the  REST conventions - update action should be either via a PUT or PATCH request. Hence following the convention we declare the route as a match which will match both PUT and PATCH requests